# Let G be a nonabelian group of order $p^3$, where $p$ is a prime number. Prove that the center of $G$ is of order $p$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory

> Let G be a nonabelian group of order $p^3$, where $p$ is a prime number. Prove that the center of $G$ is of order $p$.

**Proof**

Since $G$ is not abelian, the order of its center cannot be $p^3$. Since it is a $p$-group, the center cannot be trivial. So the order of $Z(G)$ is either $p^2$ or $p$.

Suppose, for contradiction, that $Z(G) = p^2$. Since $p$ is prime, we can assume that a subgroup $H= \langle p \rangle$ of order $p$ exists in $G$. We can also assume that $H$ and $Z(G)$ are disjoint. Otherwise, if there didn't exist a disjoint subgroup of order $p$, then the order of $G$ would be $p^2$. Since $Z(G)$ is the center, they commute with p. Since they commute with $p$, they must also commute with all powers of $p$. So $G = Z(G) \times H \implies$ G is abelian since $H$ and $Z(G)$ are abelian. So $|Z(G)|=p$.

Do you think my answer is correct?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can use that if $G/Z(G)$ is cyclic then $G$ is abelian, and then $G/Z(G)$ would have order $p$ if $Z(G)=p^2$ and hence it would be cyclic implying $G$ is abelian .

Comment: @user1044 Thanks a lot. That's a much shorter proof. But I'm just wondering...is my answer still correct?

Comment: Just a clarification when you write $H=\langle p \rangle $ do you mean $p$ is an element of $G$ (I am checking the details now)

Comment: @user1044 Yes...I should have clarified that...

Comment: Your proof contains several things I don't understand. How do you conclude that $G\cong Z(G)\times H$? When you say $H$ and $Z(G)$ are disjoint, do you mean they have trivial intersection? Why is that the case?

Comment: But how do you know $p \in G$ ? The only thing you know is that $G$ is non abelian, you can say that since $p \mid \# G$ then by Sylow's first theorem there is an element $a$ of order $p$.

Comment: @Artus I just noticed something $H$ is cyclic and hence abelian then $H \subset Z(G)$ they can't be disjoint.

Comment: @user10444 Thanks for your comment about $p \in G$. Actually I meant that $p$ represents an element in $G$, not that the "number" $p$ is in $G$. Anyway, my notation was a bit weird, and it didn't make sense...so thanks for your comment.

Comment: @julien I mixed the up, I forgot the element has to commute with all the group.

Comment: @IttayWeiss I'm not sure...maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: @Artus could you clarify on why $H$and $Z(G)$ are disjoint suppose I take $x\in H \cap Z(G) \not= e_G$ then what?

Comment: @user10444 Yeah, that's why I'm probably wrong...

Comment: [Mostly the same question, though not for proof verification](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1859133/order-of-a-center-of-a-group-is-prime-order?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't think the proof is correct.
The following doesn't make sense to me.

> We can also assume that $H$ and $Z(G)$ are disjoint. Otherwise, if there didn't exist a disjoint subgroup of order $p$, then the order of $G$ would be $p^2$.

As pointed out by user10444, typically you apply the statement

> If G/Z(G) is cyclic, then $G$ is abelian.

to exclude the case $\lvert Z(G)\rvert = p^2$.

The statement is not hard to show: Let $gZ(G)$ be a generator of the cyclic group $G/Z(G)$. Then $G = \langle \{g\}\cup Z(G)\rangle$. Since each pair of generators of $G$ commutes, $G$ is abelian.

Answer (score 13):

<strike>I have a question can somebody please clarify. Why is the possibility that $|Z(G)|=1$ not considered? Thanks!</strike>

**UPDATE:**

Here is my attempt at a solution.

Consider $Z(G)$ center of the group $G$.
We know that $Z(G)\leq G$.

By Lagrange's Theorem $|Z(G)|$ must divide $|G|$.

Since $|G|=p^{3}$ the only possibilities are $1, p, p^{2}, p^{3}$.

$|Z(G)|\neq p^{3}$ because otherwise we will have $Z(G)=G$ but $G$ is non-abelian.

$|Z(G)|\neq p^{2}$ also because otherwise we will have the order of the factor group by the center as $|G/Z(G)|=|G|/|Z(G)|= p^{3}/p^{2} = p$.

We have:

$|G/Z(G)|=p \implies G/Z(G)$ is cyclic $\implies G$ is abelian. But $G$ is non-abelian.

Now $|Z(G)|\neq 1$ also because $G$ is a $p-group$ and $p-groups$ have non-trivial center.

(thanks to Tobias Kildetoft for pointing this out).

Thus the only possible order for $Z(G)$ is $p$.

**$QED$**

Comment: I realize you do not have the required rep to comment, but please don't post answers asking for clarifications. The reason $|Z(G)|=1$ is not considered is that it is a well-known result that the center of a $p$-group is non-trivial.

Comment: Sorry about striking out the first sentence of your post. A flagger thinks it is not an answer, because you asked for clarification there. Granted, you did not answer the question *Do you think my answer is correct?*, so the flag is not without merit in that sense.

Comment: Sorry to comment on a 8 years old answer, but I don't quite get why $\vert Z(G) \vert = p^{2} $ have been discarded?

Comment: @AKP2002 Because then anything outside the center would then commute with everything, so the group would be abelian, contrary to hypothesis.

Answer (score 2):

Slightly different approach:

The conjugacy class equation $|G|=|Z|+\sum_{a\notin Z}\frac{|G|}{|N(a)|}\rightarrow p\mid|Z|$

$G$ non-abelian $\rightarrow |Z|=p$ or $p^2$

Let $a\in G,a\notin Z\rightarrow N(a)\neq G$

$a\notin Z \wedge a\in N(a)\rightarrow Z<N(a)<G$

$\rightarrow |N(a)|=p^2$ and $|Z|=p$