# $G$ a non-abelian group of order $p^3$. Show that $Inn(G)$ is abelian.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups, p-groups

> Let $G$ be a non-abelian group of order $p^3$ for prime $p$. Show that
>   $Inn(G)$ is abelian.

The center of $G$, $Z(G)$, is of order $p$ (can be seen in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/443710/let-g-be-a-nonabelian-group-of-order-p3-where-p-is-a-prime-number-prove-t)). I also know that $G / Z(G)=Inn(G) \Rightarrow \frac{p^3}{p}=p^2=|Inn(G)|$. How can I proceed and show $Inn(G)$ is abelian?

Comment: There are only two groups of order $p^2$: the cyclic group and $C_p\times C_p$.

Comment: @QuangHoang I'm not sure how that helps, sorry.

Comment: But did you just say that the order of $Inn(G)$ is $p^2$?

Comment: @QuangHoang oh yes, sorry. So if $Inn(G)$ is the cyclic group, then it is abelian? How do I show it's the cyclic group and not $C_p \times C_p$?

Comment: It's actually $C_p\times C_p$.

Comment: @QuangHoang why? And is $C_p \times C_p$ also abelian?

Comment: I'm considering answering the question, but this comment exchange is making me reconsider. There are very basic theorems that you should prove (that would answer two questions you've asked in comments): 1) Cyclic groups are abelian, and 2) Direct products of abelian groups are abelian.

Comment: @pjs36 Thank you for the feedback. I am no group theory expert but would certainly appreciate an answer, even if it's just a helpful hint. My understanding at this point is that $Inn(G)$ is either the cyclic group or $C_p \times C_p$. I'm not sure why it's the latter but it sounds like it doesn't matter, as both these groups are abelian and thus $Inn(G)$ is as well. Does that sound right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can prove that any group $G$ of order $p^2$ is abelian.

If $|Z(G)|=p^2$, then done. If $|Z(G)|=p$, then $G/Z(G)=p$ and so $G/Z(G)$ is cyclic. Suppose $hZ(G) (h\in G,h\notin Z(G))$ is the generator of $G/Z(G)$. Then for any $g_1,g_2\in G$, there is $g_1=h^nz_1, g_2=h^mz_2$, where $z_1,z_2\in Z(G)$. Thus
$$
g_1g_2=h^nz_1h^mz_2=h^nh^mz_1z_2=h^mz_2h^nz_1=g_2g_1
$$

Comment: I think you mean $h\not\in Z(G)$ while supposing $hZ(G)$ generates $G/Z(G)$, right?