# Order of a center of a group is prime order

Tags: group-theory

> **Question** :
>   Suppose that $G$ is a non-abelian group of order $p^{3}$ where $p$ is prime and 
>   $Z (G) \neq \{e\}$.
>   Prove that $|Z (G)| =p$.

Any useful hint to this question is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried? Do you think the order of the center can be $1?$ And can it be $p^2?$

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/443710/let-g-be-a-nonabelian-group-of-order-p3-where-p-is-a-prime-number-prove-t?rq=1

Comment: A fact is that the center of a group G is a subgroup of a group G. I'm trying to work from another fact that any grup of prime order is cyclic.

Comment: @Mathematicing This question has been asked several time.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Let G be a nonabelian group of order $p^3$, where $p$ is a prime number. Prove that the center of $G$ is of order $p$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/443710/let-g-be-a-nonabelian-group-of-order-p3-where-p-is-a-prime-number-prove-t)

Answer (score 9):

Since the center is non trivial his order can be $p,p^2$ or $p^3$. But $G$ is non abelian, so $|Z (G)|\neq p^3$.

Also if $|Z (G)|=p^2$, then $|G/Z|=p$, so $G/Z$ is cyclic, so $G$ is abelian ([proof here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/63087/if-g-zg-is-cyclic-then-g-is-abelian)).

Finally $|Z (G)|=p$.

Comment: I never remember, how to construct a non abelian $|H| = p^2$ ?

Comment: What is $H$ ? ${}$

Comment: Well all the groups of order $p^2$ are abelian, so you can't find such a group.

Comment: yes that's what I just thought, with the same argument you used. How to construct  $|G| = p^3$ non abelian then ?

Comment: How does the fact that the center is non trivial lead us to deduce the possible order of the center as p, $p^{2}$ or $p^{3}$.

Comment: @user1952009 You can try a semidirect product $\;C_{p^2}\rtimes C_p\;$, or even use matrices (google Heisenberg Group)

Comment: @Mathematicing Use Lagrange's theorem + what are the possible divisors of $\;p^3\;$ .

Comment: If $p=2$ you have $D_4$ and $Q_8$, if $p$ is odd you have $\mathbb{Z}_{p^2} \rtimes \mathbb{Z}_p$ and $(\mathbb{Z}_p \times \mathbb{Z}_p) \rtimes \mathbb{Z}_p$

Comment: ok so the answer is really the [Semidirect_product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semidirect_product)

Comment: Factor group of a cyclic group is cyclic. But wait! How do we even know that G is cyclic? I do not have my full stock of theorem with me atm which is a source of great frustration. ..

Comment: $|G/Z|$ is of order $p$ and all the groups of order $p$ are cyclic.

Comment: What about G having order $p^{3}$ implying the center of a group not being $p^{3}$?

Comment: @Mathematicing the center is an abelian (sub)group. If the full group is non-abelian the center cannot be the  full group.