# Let G be non abelian and |G| = $p^3$ , where p is a prime. Prove that Z(G) = G′ . What is the order of Z(G)?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

Let G be non-abelian and |G| = $p^3$
, where p is a prime. Prove that Z(G) = G′
.
What is the order of Z(G)?

Comment: Please include your own thoughts on the problem. Did you do either part? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: This has definitely been asked before here.

Comment: Concerning the order of $Z(G)$, see also [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/443710/let-g-be-a-nonabelian-group-of-order-p3-where-p-is-a-prime-number-prove-t?rq=1).